ObjectBox schema change
How can we change the DB schema on OBX Sync Server automatically?

N partners uses our app with OBX sync
Server runs on RPi
App updates comes from AppStore / Google Play Store

For example: we change our Product object, and add a new property "recyclable" (required bool, default false).
We change the schema in our app, build it, and upload to the stores. Since we oblige our users to use the latest version, so they download it as soon as a new version is available. The "recyclable" feature is already included in the new version of the app, but not yet on the Sync server. How we can change the schema on the RPi automatically?
Or we can do it only manually? (In the case of 1000 partners, this is not only a very difficult task, but also time-consuming, which may even take days...)

There's no automatic update for sync servers at this point. In your case with 1000 sync servers this would make sense though... Talk to us directly, maybe we can plan that on our roadmap assuming we enter some kind of partnership.
